# MySQL - Invalid use of group function with SUM

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm getting the error message '#1111 - Invalid use of group function' with the following query and I'm not entirely sure why.

I originally had each of the three components of the SUM as individual views (you can see the remnants of that setup in the JOIN list), but it was taking too long to run that view due to not being able to use indexes in joining view.

```
SELECT 
    `VehicleClaim`.`id` AS `Vehicle_claim_id`, `VehicleClaim`.`Vehicle_registration_number`,
    `Claim`.`id` AS `claim_id`, `Claim`.`created` AS `claim_created`, DATE_FORMAT(`Claim`.`created`, '%b') AS `claim_created_month`,
    `ClaimSubtype`.`name` AS `claim_subtype`,
    `Vendor`.`name` as `vendor_name`,

    IF(`VehicleClaim`.`id` IS NOT NULL,
        IF(`VehicleClaimUpdate`.`id` IS NOT NULL, `VehicleClaimUpdateStatus`.`status`, `ClaimStatus`.`status`), 
        IF(`ClaimUpdate`.`id` IS NOT NULL, `ClaimUpdateStatus`.`status`, `ClaimStatus`.`status`)
    ) AS `status`,

    IF(`VehicleClaimUpdate`.`id` IS NOT NULL, `VehicleClaimUpdate`.`result`,
        IF(`ClaimUpdate`.`id` IS NOT NULL, `ClaimUpdate`.`result`, NULL)
    ) AS `result`,

    SUM(
        (IF((`VehicleClaimUpdate`.`conceded_labour_cost` is not null),
            `VehicleClaimUpdate`.`conceded_labour_cost`,
            IF((`ClaimUpdate`.`id` is not null),
                `ClaimUpdate`.`conceded_labour_cost`,
                IF((`Claim`.`repair_order_id` is not null),
                    IF((`RepairOrder`.`cost` is not null),
                        `RepairOrder`.`cost`,
                        SUM((`RepairOrder`.`removal_refit_hours` * `RepairOrderHourlyRate`.`rate`))
                    ),
                    IF((`VehicleClaim`.`id` is not null),SUM((`VehicleClaim`.`work_hours` * `VehicleClaimHourlyRate`.`rate`)),0)
                )
            )
        ))
        + 
        (IF((`VehicleClaimUpdate`.`conceded_material_cost` is not null),
            `VehicleClaimUpdate`.`conceded_material_cost`,
            IF((`ClaimUpdate`.`id` is not null),
                `ClaimUpdate`.`conceded_material_cost`,
                IF((`ClaimMaterial`.`id` is not null),SUM((((`ClaimMaterial`.`unit_cost` * `ClaimMaterial`.`quantity`) * `ClaimMaterial`.`percentage_claimed`) / 100)),0)
            )
        ))
        +
        (IF(`VehicleClaimUpdate`.`conceded_freight_cost` IS NOT NULL,
            `VehicleClaimUpdate`.`conceded_freight_cost`,
            IF(`ClaimUpdate`.`id` IS NOT NULL,
                `ClaimUpdate`.`conceded_freight_cost`,
                IF(`ClaimFreight`.`id` IS NOT NULL, `ClaimFreight`.`cost`, 0)
            )
        ))
    ) AS `total_cost`,

    `User`.`id` AS `user_id`, `User`.`username`,
    `Client`.`id` AS `client_id`
FROM `Vehicle_claims` AS `VehicleClaim` 
    RIGHT JOIN `claims`                     AS `Claim` ON (`Claim`.`id` = `VehicleClaim`.`claim_id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `claim_materials`             AS `ClaimMaterial` ON (`ClaimMaterial`.`claim_id` = `Claim`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `claim_freight`               AS `ClaimFreight` ON (`ClaimFreight`.`claim_id` = `Claim`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `claim_subtypes`              AS `ClaimSubtype` ON (`ClaimSubtype`.`id` = `Claim`.`claim_subtype_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `repair_orders`               AS `RepairOrder` ON (`RepairOrder`.`id` = `Claim`.`repair_order_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `hourly_rates`                AS `RepairOrderHourlyRate` ON (`RepairOrderHourlyRate`.`id` = `RepairOrder`.`hourly_rate_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `hourly_rates`                AS `VehicleClaimHourlyRate` ON (`VehicleClaimHourlyRate`.`id` = `VehicleClaim`.`hourly_rate_id`)
    -- LEFT JOIN `view_final_material_cost` AS `FinalMaterialCost` ON (`FinalMaterialCost`.`claim_id` = `Claim`.`id` AND `FinalMaterialCost`.`Vehicle_claim_id` = `VehicleClaim`.`id`)
    -- LEFT JOIN `view_final_freight_cost`      AS `FinalFreightCost` ON (`FinalFreightCost`.`claim_id` = `Claim`.`id` AND `FinalFreightCost`.`Vehicle_claim_id` = `VehicleClaim`.`id`)
    -- LEFT JOIN `view_final_labour_cost`       AS `FinalLabourCost` ON (`FinalLabourCost`.`claim_id` = `Claim`.`id` AND `FinalLabourCost`.`Vehicle_claim_id` = `VehicleClaim`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `vendor_contacts`             AS `VendorContact` ON (`VendorContact`.`id` = `Claim`.`vendor_contact_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `vendors`                     AS `Vendor` ON (`Vendor`.`id` = `VendorContact`.`vendor_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `users`                       AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = `Claim`.`user_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `clients`                     AS `Client` ON (`Client`.`id` = `Claim`.`client_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `claim_statuses`              AS `ClaimStatus` ON (`ClaimStatus`.`id` = `Claim`.`claim_status_id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `claim_updates`               AS `ClaimUpdate` ON (`ClaimUpdate`.`id` = `Claim`.`claim_update_id`)
    left join `claim_statuses`              AS `ClaimUpdateStatus` on (`ClaimUpdateStatus`.`id` = `ClaimUpdate`.`claim_status_id`)
    left join `claim_statuses`              AS `VehicleClaimStatus` on (`ClaimStatus`.`id` = `VehicleClaim`.`claim_status_id`)
    LEFT JOIN `claim_updates`               AS `VehicleClaimUpdate` ON (`VehicleClaimUpdate`.`id` = `VehicleClaim`.`claim_update_id`) 
    left join `claim_statuses`              AS `VehicleClaimUpdateStatus` on (`VehicleClaimUpdateStatus`.`id` = `VehicleClaimUpdate`.`claim_status_id`)
WHERE YEAR(`Claim`.`created`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY `VehicleClaim`.`id`
```

Comment: Check if your result set contains duplicate sum. If so, then GROUP functions will work definitely. Basically, GROUP is not useful when the result set contains unique values.

Comment: Problem seems to be that you use `SUM()` inside of `SUM()`. I can reproduce the same error message with a simple
`
    > select sum(sum(id)) from t1;
    ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
`

Comment: Hooray for RIGHT JOIN!

Comment: Strawberry, sarcasm?

Hartmut Holzgraefe: I believe you are correct!

Would moving each of the three SUM components to be JOINS work, or would I suffer the same performance as when they were separate views? As I assume the JOIN creates a derived dataset which then can't be joined via indexes?